# Manipulating background-colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What am I doing wrong here?

I am trying to get the background color to change using jquery, on document loaded but it won't any idea why?

http://jsfiddle.net/KczZd/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="myTabs">
    <div class="ajax__tab_active">
        <div class=".ajax__tab_inner" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;" >

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myTabs .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_inner{
 width:100px;
 background-color:green;   
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myTabs .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_inner').css('background-color', red);
});
```

Comment: Always include the code in the question in addition to a link.  The idea is to keep this site as self-sufficient as possible.  If jsfiddle disappears the question will still be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`red` isn't declared, much the same as `primaryColor` wasn't in your old JSFiddle. You need to make it a string instead:

```
$('.myTabs .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_inner').css('background-color', 'red');
```

---

#### Before update

You haven't declared `primaryColor`. Declare it and assign it a colour before your `$.css()` line:

```
var primaryColor = '#f00';    // Red

$('.myTabs .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_inner').css('background-color', primaryColor);
```

Firebug's console gives my this error:

```
primaryColor is not defined
```

You should always have a debug console open when developing JavaScript; it makes fixing bugs much easier.

Comment: there might be a selector error in there too, but this is a definite showstopper.

Comment: Apologies, submitted this question before it was completed, please view updated fiddle link.

Comment: and . fullstop sigh I need sleep to many mistakes to quick! thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You assigned your inner div the class .ajax__tab_inner. Get rid of the period.

```
<div class="ajax__tab_inner" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;" >
```

Comment: Apologies, submitted this question before it was completed, please view updated fiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues,

1. In your markup you had used  `<div class=".ajax__tab_inner"` Change it to  `<div class="ajax__tab_inner"`
2. primaryColor was not defined.. Define primaryColor before .css.

Fixed Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/KczZd/8/)

**Edit**: In your updated fiddle, color red was not inside quotes.. change it to `.css('background-color', 'red');`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the dot in front of ajax__tab_inner in your html.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo or copy/paste problem in your markup

```
<div class=".ajax__tab_inner" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;" >
```

Remove the `.` from the class name in the above div element, it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/KczZd/13/